# How to abstract different data sources for Object generation?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Im working on a project that displays data from objects in a specific way as images. The data that is stored in form of the objects comes from different datasources, e.g. two .json files OR one csv file OR three .yaml files OR a database OR something different, added in the future and not known at the moment.

I already googled for a few hours, repository pattern, DAO, abstract factory pattern are words that i stumbled up on but i think that none of them really matches my use case. Im just learning about design etc., i know the basic patterns and how to use them but maybe im not knowing enough to get my head around why the above mentioned patterns work?

My question: how would you design the software so that the businesslogic (hydrating my objects with information) is abstracted from how many and what kind of data sources are used?